# Flutter How to use Retrofit for different environments (Flavors)

Tags: flutter, retrofit, flutter-bloc, dio

I want to use [Retrofit](https://pub.dev/packages/retrofit) client generation. I need to support two environments (dev and prod).

How to configure my RestClient class to support both environments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution1 - Easy implementation

Pass a different baseUrl depending on your entry point.

According to [Retrofit official documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/retrofit#multiple-endpoints-support), you can pass the baseUrl on run time. In other words, you can give different base URLs on different entry points.

### Solution2 - Using `Injectable` and `GetIt`

Thanks to leoshusar [solution on Github](https://github.com/trevorwang/retrofit.dart/issues/490#issuecomment-1214212442),

You can use `Injectable` for DI (dependency injection) with different configurations to the `Retrofit` RestApi service, based on the running environment.

**Checkout the [full detailed example](https://github.com/leoshusar/flutter-di-showcase) on GitHub.**